# Remove active cell when slickgrid focus is lost

Tags: slickgrid

I have multiple instances of slickgrids visible on the page.  However, I would only like one grid to have an active cell at a time (almost as if multiple grids act like one unified grid).  Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to onActiveCellChanged for every grid and call resetActiveCell() on all the other instances.